# Using boost variant with template deduction

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following class:

```
template <typename classTypeT>
class myClass {
public:    
    using FunctionType1 = std::function<void(classTypeT &, const std::string*)>;
    using FunctionType2 = std::function<void(classTypeT &, const int)>;
    using FunctionVariantType = boost::variant<FunctionType1, FunctionType2>;

    std::vector<FunctionVariantType> myVariants;

    myClass(const std::vector<FunctionVariantType> myVec) {
        myVariants = myVec;
    }
};
```

And creating an instance of that class:

```
auto vec = std::vector<myClass<SomeOtherClass>::FunctionVariantType>({&SomeOtherClass::someFunc});
auto classInstance = myClass<SomeOtherClass>(vec);
```

This code works and does what I want, but I'd really want to avoid having to specify the template type in the vector. I.E., I want to be able to do this:

```
auto vec = std::vector({&SomeOtherClass::someFunc});
auto classInstance = myClass<SomeOtherClass>(vec); // Error
```

And have some template deuction, but I'm getting an error like this:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<void (__cdecl myClass::* )(const std::string *),std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'const std::vector<mwboost::variant<std::function<void (classTypeT &,const std::string *)>,std::function<void (classTypeT &, const int)>>,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
```

It looks like it can't implicitly cast the function type to a variant of that function type? This seems to work better without the vector, but shouldn't I still be able to do this?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Look at the `auto vec = std::vector({&SomeOtherClass::someFunc});` line in complete isolation. How is that line of code supposed to know `boost::variant` and `std::function` are expected to be involved here? Or in other words: if you were a compiler which type would you replace `auto` with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take an [`initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) of `FunctionVariantType`:

```
template <typename T>
class myClass {
public:
    using FunctionType1 = std::function<void(T&, const std::string*)>;
    using FunctionType2 = std::function<void(T&, const int)>;
    using FunctionVariantType = std::variant<FunctionType1, FunctionType2>;

    std::vector<FunctionVariantType> myVariants;

    myClass(std::initializer_list<FunctionVariantType> myVec)
        : myVariants(myVec) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto func1 = [](int&, const std::string*) {};
    auto func2 = [](int&, const int) {};

    myClass<int> myInst({func1, func2});
}
```

This works because `vector` also has a constructor taking an `initializer_list`.

Comment: This ended up being a better appraoch than what I was trying to do with the vector. Thanks!

Comment: @rmsantos: it is the same approach as your. Your problem is to use intermediate variable instead of using `{func1, func2}` directly in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `A` is convertible to `B`, `std::vector<A>` is not convertible to `std::vector<B>`.

But you can easily construct `std::vector<B>` from `std::vector<A>` with iterator constructor:

```
auto vec = std::vector({&SomeOtherClass::someFunc});
auto classInstance = myClass<SomeOtherClass>({vec.begin(), vec.end()});
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for OP, as they'll almost certainly want `vec` to be heterogenous in the first place.

Comment: @Frank: OP can stil omit `vec` variable and directly do `myClass<SomeOtherClass>({& func1, &func2, & func3});`.

Comment: yes, obviously, I was sort of assuming that the indirection through `vec` was a hard requirement, but if that's not the case, that would make this a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely MUST go through that intermediate `vec` variable, then I think the best way to tackle this would be to hold the compiler by the hand a bit and guide it through the process.

In your specific case, I would go about it along these general lines:

```
template <typename classTypeT>
class myClass {
public:
  [...]

  template<typename... Args>
  static auto make_vtable(Args&&... args) {
     return std::vector<FunctionVariantType>({std::forward<Args>(args)...});
  }
}
```

And creating an instance of the class:

```
using class_type = myClass<SomeOtherClass>;

auto vec = class_type::make_vtable(&SomeOtherClass::someFunc, &SomeOtherClass::someOtherFunc);
auto classInstance = class_type(vec);
```